# How To Implement A Five Star Rating System in Access 2016 with VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Greetings Stackoverflow,

I'm writing a material database that we use for our university and I was trying to implement a 5 star rating system for materials entered into the ms-access 2016 database system. I have most of the ground work done, but I'm having coding errors.

I think it might have something to do with the coding script from an example from 2007 version that I'm trying to add into my own program. I'm kinda a beginner in designing and coding, so forgive any missteps.

This is what I have:

There is a vba module with the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function SetRating(frm As Object, ctl As Access.Control)

'Code: by Daniel van den Berg

On Error GoTo Err_handler

Dim strStar As String
Dim strBlank As String

' set path to picture accordingly
strStar = "C:\Users\jason\Pictures\yellow_sm.png"
strBlank = "C:\Users\jason\Pictures\blank_sm.png"

Select Case ctl.Value

Case Is = 0

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strBlank

Case Is = 1

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strBlank

Case Is = 2

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strBlank

Case Is = 3

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strBlank
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strBlank

Case Is = 4

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strBlank

Case Is = 5

frm.imgSt1.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt2.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt3.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt4.Picture = strStar
frm.imgSt5.Picture = strStar

End Select


Exit_err:

Exit Function


Err_handler:

MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

Resume Exit_err:


End Function
```

---

In the form, I have the following as an event procedures

```
Private Sub cmdNoRating_Click()

NoRating Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

SetRating Form_Material Details, Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub imgSt1_Click()

SetRatingClick Me.imgSt1, Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub imgSt2_Click()

SetRatingClick Me.imgSt2, Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub imgSt3_Click()

SetRatingClick Me.imgSt3, Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub imgSt4_Click()

SetRatingClick Me.imgSt4, Me.mRating

End Sub

Private Sub imgSt5_Click()

SetRatingClick Me.imgSt5, Me.mRating

End Sub
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, it would help if you would include the full code of  the SetRating function. What you have included now does exactly nothing.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I've updated the code. Hope it helps

Comment: What exactly is the error you receive? When do you receive it? Also, what is this: `Private Sub Form_Current()

SetRating Form_Material Details, Me.mRating

End Sub` supposed to do? It passes the wrong number of arguments to SetRating.

Comment: As soon as I load the form, I get a Syntax Error for the following code Private Sub Form_Current()

SetRating Form_Material Details, Me.mRating

End Sub

Comment: Not sure, I was apart of the code structure that I used from another example application @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth seems like just deleting the Private Sub you identified made it work correctly

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Ah, I think I understand what it's support to do. Once I exit the form, it doesn't save or reset the star rating from one record to the next. It saves the value, but that value isn't represented from the star rating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong number of arguments to the `SetRating` function in the `Form_Current` event, and also using variables that aren't set.

Try replacing it with this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
      SetRating Me.Form, Me.mRating
End Sub
```

Also, note that just copy-pasting VBA that you don't fully understand in a production environment is a security hazard. Try to read into your code.

Note that deleting it will probably have caused the rating not to load when you refresh the form or switch records.

Comment: That did it! I thank you so very kindly!!! I'm sure it was quite simple for you, it took me nearly all day :D